# «Devdays will return not until spring 2011», any news?

Tags: discussion, devdays

Remember [Joel announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/devdays/) posted June 24th, 2010?

> **Devdays** will return **not until
> 2011**
> ..
> Instead of me doing everything, we’ll
> find some way for the community to
> help plan the agenda, especially when
> it comes to choosing speakers. And,
> ultimately, that probably means that
> we’re looking at **Spring 2011**

We are already in 2011 and spring season is near.

Are there any plans for an awesome 2011 edition of Devdays?

Comment: _[Who knows...](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/552342#552342)_

Comment: Would you consider registering at http://t.co/nmD9V10 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are working on it!

[Start here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86663/devdays-2011-straw-poll-one-day-or-two).

**UPDATE (2011-09-06):** [DevDays 2011 is Cancelled](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/), but **if you're still interested in attending 'something' in London**, please look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105425/devdays-cancelled-should-we-have-a-london-meetup-anyway).

Answer (score 3):

There's this interesting initiative going on:

### [Stack Overflow MeetUps – April 6](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-meetups-april-6/)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: According to [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/), DevDays 2011 has been canceled.

<sub>*For original answer, see [the revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/88210/revisions).*</sub>