# DevDays 2011 - straw poll - one day or two?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2011

We're just starting to kick around some ideas for Stack Overflow DevDays 2011, and need your feedback. This is the first part of that; watch the [devdays-2011](/questions/tagged/devdays-2011) tag for other questions.

Assume:

- three cities (San Francisco, Washington, London). We may do more cities, but for the purpose of this question, imagine that we're only going to be in those three places.

The question is -- one day or two?

One day would cost $199 and be a lot like the last DevDays. (Yeah, it's more expensive than last time. Unfortunately last time we really killed ourselves trying to get the price as low as it was in 2009, skimping on necessities like internet access and coffee).

Two days would cost $399 and provide a lot more time for socializing, more in-depth talks, and possibly some opportunities for break-out sessions, birds-of-a-feather, and interesting socializing.

Comment: In the two day scenario, would there be one day passes for those who can only (afford | attend) one day?

Comment: No. The costs to the organizers are the same (venue, internet, etc) whether you attend for one day or two.

Comment: In which option is the swag better?

Comment: we'll use the extra buck from the two day event for a sticker :)

Comment: No Austin? I suppose I don't have a dog in this hunt. However, I will through out that you should annoy the marketing folks by charging $201 or $401.

Comment: Forget Austin, there's not even an NYC!

Comment: don't focus on the city choice. We'll do a city survey later. I just listed three certain cities because people's willingness to travel may affect whether they want to go for 1 day or 2.

Comment: Should we perhaps add two more options: "*probably* attend 2 days, $399", and "*probably* attend 1 day, $199"?  Even though I really want to go, the word "definitely" scares me because a) programmers are scared of commitments, and b) pedantically, how can anything be definite?  Stuff happens!  :)

Comment: I see no mention of dates.

Comment: I don't drink coffee.  We can skip the coffee.  And I can live without the internets for a day.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## Two days - $399.

Vote for this answer if you would definitely attend a two-day Stack Overflow DevDays at $399 in San Francisco, Washington, or London.

Comment: If I'm gonna fly to a conference I'd like it to last longer than one day.

Comment: Definitely two days! I think the emphasis on socialization can not be overstated. While DevDays 2009 was awesome, it was (overall) very short and there was very little opportunity to mingle. Although the conversations I did have were great, there were far too few of them.

Comment: I totally agree with @jinguy and @Pandincus - with 2 days you have the evening/breakfast between the days for socializing, tech chat, startup idea sharing etc. In addition if I have to fly (from T.O. that's likely the only valid option) its much easier to "sell" to MGMT as a dev conference if there's at least 2 days of content ;-)

Comment: @scunliffe I love that band.

Comment: It depends on the location, but two days justifies more travel time.

Comment: Damn that is pricey!

Comment: What happened to NY and Boston?  Washington (DC I assume)?  I can see the attraction for going to a museum or a memorial, but a DevDays event?  Why?  It is harder for me to sell management on missing two days of work instead of 1.

Comment: @Joel why have you updated the cost to $599 (-$100 with foo code)?

Answer (score 33):

## One day - $199.

Vote for this answer if you would definitely attend a one day Stack Overflow DevDays at $199 in San Francisco, Washington, or London.

Comment: I would go to one in Boston or NY as well

Answer (score 10):

### Zero Days - $263.

Vote for this if you booked for a conference and have non-refundable airline tickets and/or accommodation in an expensive city such as San Franciso, Washington or London.